# Calling Python Django File in Android Java Code

Tags: php, android, python, django

I'm developing an android app in Java. I was using a php file to interact w/ the database, but I want to use Python Django instead of php. Could I call the python file that interacts with the database in the same way that I called the php file?

```
URL url = new URL("http://10.0.3.2/MYCODE/app/login.php");

String urlParams = "name="+name+"&password="+password;

HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Another more general question is how do I API Java and Python Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a python socket server and interface with that using your app.  There are many ways to do this though.  I created a very small python socket server [here](https://github.com/rstims/lightweight-python-socket-server), you're welcome to use it, of course.

[Java Socket Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html)

Comment: Also, for the last question, I haven't done a python api, but I found this - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/